# Heroku H12 errors with Django

Tags: django, heroku

I have a Djano 1.8 application running on 6 Heroku dynos. Every once in a while, a request that is normally very fast (200ms) comes in and hits the Heroku router 30 second timeout. Then that dyno times out other follow-on requests, sometimes taking 25 minutes to stabilize and go back to serving requests without timing out.

I'm using gunicorn with default web_concurrency (2 workers per dyno). I read Heroku's article on timeout behavior [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#timeout-behavior), and am considering adding something like --timeout 20 to my gunicorn startup in the Procfile. That seems to be what they are recommending. Do you think that will solve the problem? From looking at the [gunicorn documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html) on the timeout setting it says:

```
Workers silent for more than this many seconds are killed and restarted.
```

But my workers aren't silent are they? They are trying to process requests but are hung and unable to for some reason. Also, when I run gunicorn -h I can see that the default setting for timeout is 30. So if that shouldn't the long running task on my app be killed well before 5, 10 minutes, etc. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: This is exactly my problem as well: Django 1.8 with 3 Heroku standard-1x dynos but every few days one dyno goes "bad". All future requests to that one dyno timeout but it's still "alive" and taking new requests (which also timeout) and the dyno doesn't seem to fix itself or restart. I manually restart the dyno after a few minutes and it runs great until several days later when it happens again. This just started happening a few weeks ago. Did you figure anything out?